# Is it safe to OPTIMIZE MySQL database using Optimize Table option in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: magento-1.7, database, optimization

Looking to optimize MySQL database for magento using the ***Optimize table*** option in phpMyAdmin?

Are there any risks to optimize using such option?

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by optimizing a table?  What are is your `innodb_file_per_table` setting?  Is there a `FULLTEXT` index on the table?  What is your MySQL Server Version?

Comment: @icon Please view my profile, Network profile for contact information and check out our web presence.  Our FAQ has some Optimize info that you will find helpful. Thanks